# How to display data to Trading view chart using Alpha Vantage API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
const cdata = data.map(d => {
{time:d[0],open:[1],high[2],low[3],close[4]} 
});
candleSeries.setData(cdata);
})
.catch(err => log(err))
```

[This My API DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHgM.png)

When I run this code, there have an error like data.map is not function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Add Return before {time:d[0],open:[1],high[2],low[3],close[4]}

It's Like this
return {time:d[0],open:[1],high[2],low[3],close[4]}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).